# @Input: Two way data binding not working

Tags: angular, data-binding

I am trying to replicate this: http://plnkr.co/edit/OB2YTMJyeY3h9FOaztak?p=preview *(this plunker is the example that works, and I want to get the same result but with my code, that isn't working)*

==================================================================

I have this simple two way binding, I am trying to update a string property such on the parent as on the child

**The problem:** when clicking "**update from parent**", both bindings update. But when clicking "**update from child**", only the childs updates!

This seems very simple, what can I be doing wrong?

(*Note: I used angular CLI for running up the project*)

==================================================================

**Parent component:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-dad',
  templateUrl: './my-dad.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-dad.component.css']
})
export class MyDadComponent {

  parentModel: string;

  constructor() {}

  updateModel(){
    this.parentModel += ' parent';
  }
}
```

**Parent template**

```
<h2>Parent: {{ parentModel }} </h2> 
<button (click)="updateModel()"> update from parent </button>

<app-my-child [(model)]="parentModel"></app-my-child>
```

**Child component**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-child',
  templateUrl: './my-child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-child.component.css']
})
export class MyChildComponent {

  @Input() model: string;

  constructor() { }

  updateModel(){
    this.model += ' child';
  }
}
```

**Child template:**

```
<h2>Child: {{ model }} </h2>
<button (click)="updateModel()"> update from child </button>
```

Answer (score 23):

For two-way-binding using the `[(xxx)]` (banana-in-a-box) syntax, you need an `@Input()` and an `@Output()` with matching names like:

```
@Input() myProp:String;
@Output() myPropChange:EventEmitter<String> = new EventEmitter<String>();
```

See also the guide https://angular.io/docs/dart/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#two-way

For two-way-binding with `ngModel` to work, your component needs to implement `ControlValueAccessor`.

See also:

- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/NgModel-directive.html
- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11073#issuecomment-242563788

Comment: That worked! but why cant I replicated what I is in that plunker I posted? (http://plnkr.co/edit/OB2YTMJyeY3h9FOaztak?p=preview)

Maybe it is deprecated?

Thanks!

Comment: Could run the Plunker now but can't reproduce. No matter what button I press, both strings are updated.

Comment: That plunker is the example that works! But my code (wich is equally enough) don't!

Comment: Could you elaborate? I've been trying to do almost the same thing with a container class. When passing the container class to the child (`<child [(thing)]="myInstance"></child>`) and bind to `[(ngModel)]="thing.memberName"` I get the double binding to work, but not with `<child [(thing)]="myInstance.memberName"></child>`. Any input is welcome :)

Comment: The "matching names" part is important! I didn't find it in the angular docs. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 2):

To give a summarized elaboration to @Gunter above:

1. Child component must have a matching `EventEmitter` property type with the same data-type generic and decorated with `@Output()`
2. There must be call to `emit` method of the above property. This call is usually made in a method which changes the value of the child property.

So, your code must have:

1. `@Output() modelChange: EventEmitter<String> = new EventEmitter<String>();`
   in the child component.
2. `this.modelChange.emit(model);` (call to emit method) in the `updateModel()` method of the child component.